# How to transpose this code to Swift2?

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2

Code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()        
    //animation
    
    dialogView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.0, 0.0)
     }

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.7, delay: 0.1, options: nil, animations: [self.dialogView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1)], completion: nil)
```

I am getting these two errors:

> Nil is not compatible with expected argument type 'UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions'
>
> Cannot invoke 'animateWithDuration' with an argument list of type '(Double, delay: Double, options: NilLiteralConvertible, animations: [()], completion: NilLiteralConvertible)'

Comment: Your animation block isn't a closure. The completion block you have as an array, when it should be `nil` in your case.

Comment: even after what u said?.
Cannot invoke 'animateWithDuration' with an argument list of type '(Double, delay: Double, options: NilLiteralConvertible, animations: [()], completion: NilLiteralConvertible)'

Comment: Your animation block **still** isn't a closure.

Comment: can you please help me this. I'm just a week old at programming. I'm learning.

Comment: If you are new, I'd advise you not to just throw code at the compiler. The animation block you have is wrapped in strange syntax. Take a step back and try to understand what you are doing at each step. Rushing ahead is not going to help you in the long run.

Comment: yeah i do realise. I am learning by mistakes. today i have learnt something new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are having trouble understanding the syntax for this:

This is what you want to write:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    dialogView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.0, 0.0)
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
   super.viewDidAppear(animated)

   UIView.animateWithDuration(
        0.7, 
        delay: 0.1, 
        options: [], 
        animations: { () -> Void in
            self. dialogView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0)
        }, completion: nil)
}
```

The points to note here are:

- the `options` are `[]` not `nil`. the options are `UIViewAnimationOptions` which in Swift 2 are of `OptionSetType` so they are combined with Set notation not bitwise fashion. So for empty options pass an empty array.
- the `animations` parameter is a closure.
- the completion block is `nil` not an empty set.

Comment: thank you so much. put things in a better perspective. i have so far to go still :)